# Multiple DOC files to be converted to ISOSTS XML files

Tags: xml, pdf, pandoc, iso, doc

There is a high number of old and outdated DOC files that needs to be converted to ISOSTS XML files.

The actual content of the files doesn't matter, but I need to be able to convert them automatically since there are more than 40K files.

There are also some pictures in those DOC files, representing formulas and such.

What I've tried so far includes using Pandoc to convert DOCX files to JATS XML, but I couldn't find a way to convert JATS XML files to ISOSTS XML.

I need a way to actually convert, whether using a software or writing a code but I am lost. Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: What's the difference between ISOSTS and JATS? Some minor differences, or.. what's the current output and what's expected? what did you try? As currently worded, this question is not a fit for StackOverflow as it's not a coding problem.

Comment: There are no big differences between jats and niso sts because both are formats defined for academic documents but nio sts is for technical standard documents. I tried to change the xml tags with the SAXON HE library using xsl, but I could not succeed because the structure in xsl was very complex. I'm trying to get ideas from people who have dealt with this before